# My project started throwing error NegativeArraySizeException on build

Tags: intellij-idea

After my IntelliJ crashed my project started to give me following error when trying to build or run. Restarting, resetting rebuilding didn't help. Other projects work perfectly. Does anyone have a clue what else to try?

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException) null
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at com.intellij.util.io.IOUtil.readString(IOUtil.java:48)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetTypeState.load(BuildTargetTypeState.java:68)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetTypeState.<init>(BuildTargetTypeState.java:55)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetsState.getTypeState(BuildTargetsState.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetsState.getAverageBuildTime(BuildTargetsState.java:108)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.messages.BuildProgress.<init>(BuildProgress.java:70)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:364)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:229)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should help if you delete IDE [system directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me 5 years later.  Never saw this error before:
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -886571008

I was able to just build one module at a time in my project, then I was able to start the server again.   Strange!

In case anyone else experiences this weird error, just manually building fixed it for me.